# C++ error: trying to understand Classes and Constructors

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the error I am receiving:

> **error:** is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Looking into why I am getting the error, I believe it has something to do with not having a default constructor for `class Dealer`. I'm not quite understanding why that is the case in regards to this program. I believe it has to do with the `Motorcycle m_motorcycle` object I created.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Motorcycle{

public:
    string m_make;
    string m_model;
    int m_year;
    Motorcycle(string, string, int);
};

class Dealer{
private:
    Motorcycle m_motorcycles[3];
public:
    void addMotorcycle(Motorcycle);
    Motorcycle getMotorcycle(int);
};

int main(){
    Motorcycle bike1("Ductai", "Scrambler", 2020);
    Dealer dealer1;

    dealer1.addMotorcycle(bike1);
    return 0;
}

Motorcycle::Motorcycle(string make, string model, int year){
  this->m_make = make;
  this->m_model = model;
  this->m_year = year;
}
void Dealer::addMotorcycle(Motorcycle bike){
    this->m_motorcycles[0] = bike;
}
```

Comment: instead of always having 3 motorcycles per dealer, consider using a resizeable container of motorcycles (e.g. `vector<Motorcycle> m_motorcycles;`). Then this problemw ill not arise.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization of `Dealer` requires initialization of `Motorcycle m_motorcycles[3];`, when it tries to create an array of `Motorcycle` it looks for its default constructor, but only a parameterized constructor is provided.

```
class Motorcycle{
public:
    string m_make;
    string m_model;
    int m_year;
    Motorcycle(string, string, int);
    Motorcycle(){ 
        //.....
    }; 
};
```

Adding a default constructor to `Motorcycle` would be one way of fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that implicit default constructor of `class Dealer` is *deleted* since it contains `Motorcycle m_motorcycles[3];`, and `Motorcycle` has no default constructor.

A way to solve this is to include `std::vector<Motorcycle> m_motorcycles;` in `class Dealer` instead of the array, and also change `Dealer::addMotorcycle()`:

```
void Dealer::addMotorcycle(Motorcycle bike){
    this->m_motorcycles.push_back( bike );
}
```